How to use process.start() to open a report creation tool and need to send the contents of report using C#
I'm using standalone reporting designing from Telerik for WPF. I used the Process.Start method to open the tool from C#. Also I need to pass the content to the tool.
How is it possible to fulfill this requirement? Can anyone help me?
I tried to open the tool with an argument as "Mahima". But got an error from the tool.

Can you pass command line arguments to the tool if you start it from a CMD shell? Can you pass data in using a pipe (i.e., via STDIN) from the command line? Does the tool have any other programmatic interface? What exactly did you do when tried to open the tool "with an argument" and what was the error you received?

Are you 100% positive that the tool isn't actually supposed to run in-process and be accessed by a C#-Api?

I tried to open Standalone Report Designer(https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/desktop-designers/standalone-report-designer/overview). In the document they mentioned that we need to open the tool using the Process.start() .

I want to open the reporting tool from a C# WPF web application, by allowing the user to create their own report by invoking the tool at a button click.
Req: Open the standalone report tool. Pass the content from the database to the tool through the application to display the content in the report.

Is this WPF Core?

It is WPF (.NET Framework)

Syntax in .Net Framework is Process.Start(string exename, string arguments).  According to the link you provided, the Report Designer accepts a report definition file as an argument.  Please show us the actual code you are trying to use

This is my code :
string parameter = "Mahima";
Process.Start(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting 2024 Q1\Report Designer\Telerik.ReportDesigner.exe", parameter);

Is Mahima really the name of a report definition file????

No it is just a string like parameter. For the testing purpose

For the report content, I used  a string "Mahima".
